# Adding border to the element changed it`s position

Tags: css

I`m trying to add border property to my element on hover effect. And I faced some problem.

Here is my default state
http://prntscr.com/93dvjx

**What I have**

http://prntscr.com/93dwj9

When I hover my `<i>` element, css added border property to it. But it changed the position of the element, so it moves a little down and right.

Here is `<i>` CSS properties on hover:

```
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

**What I want**

When I hover the element, it stayed on it`s position just with added border outside.
What is the best way to do it?

*P.S*

I tried to apply transparent property to the border at first, but it does not help me, because it changed element width and height.
http://prntscr.com/93dz61
And I need for the element to be smaller, when it`s not hover
http://prntscr.com/93e06t

Comment: Could you add all of the css which affects your element? I could suggest if I know what positioning etc is in play.

Comment: Here is JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kyngnkth/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [`box-sizing` CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Without actual code, it's hard to determine exactly what is happening, but I suspect that your `box-sizing` is not set to `border-box`.

That property tells the rendered to include the border (and padding) when calculating the width and height of the element, instead of adding it as extra space.

Try adding it to your stylesheet and adjusting the width/height. You might get what you need.

Comment: Add `box-sizing:border-box` to the lens element (not the hover state) and it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/4ubvrrk4/

Answer (score 0):

the position changes, so change it back :)

```
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -2px;
```

I don't know if it's the best way and might need some changes but it might work.

Comment: Hardcoding these is not a very good idea. What if the sizing needs to change or the icon be animated? Will they remember to change/recalculate all these again?

Comment: Even if the size changes the border width is the same. But you are right he will need to recalculate this if he changes the hover border width.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
i
{
border:3px solid transparent;
box-sizing:border-box;
    }

i:hover{
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```